# Offsite back ups between office and home - home being the offsite location

Tags: vpn, backup, windows-server-2012, windows-backup, qnap

I'm wondering if VPN is the best solution and if so, where do I start, bit of a network novice!

Main office location: 4 PCs on a ring network, all windows 7. Connected to a BT hub thing, fixed IP address. There's also a printer on the network and a qnap storage nas device thing which they save stuff locally to.

Home: fixed business BT line with fixed IP. One micro server with windows 2012. Again a BT router hub thing.

I haven't yet but I'm pretty confident i can browse to each router and play with their local settings. Just don't really know what specifically to look for.

The idea: to use the home micro server as an offsite back up, initially to mirror the qnap then after the initial mirror, take weekly incremental back ups.

Any idea how to connect the two sites together and configure it guys?

Answer (score 0):

Tons of official complex "backup" options: rsync etc.

Use one of the cloud storage services providers (you'll be paying for storage space after their free tier): Dropbox, Google Drive, box.net etc.

Use a file/folder synchronization utility that utilizes the bit torrent protocol (no complex network port forwarding things to do): Syncthing, Bittorrent Sync.

Syncthing does have a versioning option.